# How to delete a button click event?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

In my project, there is a asp button with a C# button_Onclick handler. The problem is when you click the button on html, the event will be kept by browser. For example, the event will be sent if you refresh the browser..

I have tried add a `return;` to the end of the button_Onclick handler and  a JavaScript for thebutton_Onclick handler to call, but all fail.

asp:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Save" />
```

C#:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    .......
    return;
}
```

Comment: I should do it with javascript

Comment: I don't see btnSubmit_click registered on aspx code. It will never be called. And what do you mean by the event will be kept by browser?

Comment: @PratikGaikwad 1) it registered in page_load   2) when you refresh the browser, the event will be sent again

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? Do you want to call that event on click of button from server side or javascript side?

Comment: @kingyau you are registering it in wrong way.

Comment: @PratikGaikwad i want to kill that click event when my onclick method finished its job.

Comment: @kingyau Since you are registering the event in Page_load, it is called twice. And you want to avoid it being called second time. I am assuming that is your issue. Please confirm.

Comment: *"For example, the event will be sent if you refresh the browser.."* - Huh? Why would refreshing the browser send a click event? A `return` on the last line of a `void` function doesn't do anything, because at that point the function would return on its own anyway.

Comment: @PratikGaikwad `event.preventDefault();` on jQuery is what i want to do..Is it possible to do it in C#?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code makes a POST request when clicking the button, this is how browsers behave and should behave on refresh. They must send the submitted data again to the server. If you want to avoid this, then in your submit handler method you should do a redirect to another URL after doing whatever your handler does.

For example if `form.asp` displays your form, then in your handler you can redirect to `form.asp?message=thankyou` (notice the different URL), then in case of refresh, your form will not be sent again by the browser to the server.

Also, best would be to use a 303 redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You should redirect to another page to avoid this.But In case if you want to stay on the workaround is as follows.

In your pageload_Event capture the dateTime.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   if (!IsPostBack)
     {
       Session["update"]=Server.UrlEncode(System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
     }
 }
```

In the Page_PreRender Event Copy the sessionVariable to ViewState Variable.You can refer following to get a clear understanding on Page Life cycle. "http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/667308/ASP-NET-Page-Life-Cycle-Events"

```
  public void Page_PreRender(object obj, EventArgs e)
  {
      ViewState["update"] = Session["update"];
  }
```

Now in your button on click event compare the ViewState ans session variable.Allow into the block if both the values are equal.

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (Session["update"].ToString() == ViewState["update"].ToString())
      {
         try
         {
          -----------Your Logic
         }
         finally
         {
          Session["update"]=Server.UrlEncode(System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
         }
      }
}
```

Comment: WOW, it is too much code. Can the onclick method calls a javascrtip function for doing `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: yeah you can do it by registeting client side script  using ScriptManager class

Comment: But what is the code in that js function? simply `return false`? `event.preventDefault();` ? It do nothing when i try to do this..

Comment: I dont understand why do you need to use js in my suggested answer.My suggested answer gives a solution that even if the page is refreshed the submit click event would  be hit and the condition check would not be satisfied.